# Best way/data structure to send arguments to method

Tags: python, data-structures, arguments

Through my several Python projects, I have been wondering what was the most efficient and at the same time beautiful way to send multiple arguments to a method.

Let's say we have a method accepting the following parameters foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley, whatever the number, types and relations.

What way would be the most efficient, pythonic and elegant according to you ?

Simple argument parameters:

```
def my_func(foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley):
    # Do some stuff

my_func(foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley)
```

Through a tuple:

```
def my_func(some_tuple):
    foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley = some_tuple
    # Do some stuff

my_func((foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley))
```

With related tuples and simple parameters for lone arguments:

```
def my_func(related_parameters_tuple, other_related_parameters_tuple, spoot):
    foo, bar = related_parameters_tuple
    rick, astley = other_related_parameters_tuple
    # Do some stuff

my_func((foo, bar), (rick, astley), spoot)
```

A dictionary:

```
def my_func(dictionary):
    # Do some stuff
    # dictionary['foo']
    # dictionary['bar']
    # ...

my_func({
    'foo': foo,
    'bar': bar,
    'spoot': spoot,
    'rick': rick,
    'astley': astley
    })
```

Related dictionaries and simple parameters for lone arguments:

```
def my_func(related_parameters_dictionary, other_related_parameters_dictionary, spoot):
    # Do some stuff
    # related_parameters_dictionary['foo']
    # related_parameters_dictionary['bar']
    # other_related_parameters_dictionary['rick']
    # other_related_parameters_dictionary['astley']
    # ...

my_func({
    'foo': foo,
    'bar': bar,
    'spoot': spoot,
    'rick': rick,
    'astley': astley
    })
```

Thanks for sharing your opinions !

Comment: Of "efficient, pythonic and elegant," which do you really want? It is rare for "efficient" and "elegant" to go together.

Comment: _Definitely_ go with `def my_func(foo, bar, spoot, rick, astley):`. If two parameters are so related that you'd put them in a tuple, replace that tuple with a dedicated class instead.

Comment: "Your opinions" -> "primarily opinion-based" -> not appropriate for [so]. See [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).